# Set checkmark for static table view cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I have an iPhone app with iOS 8 and Swift.

I would like to set the checkmark accessory in a static table view with 3 rows. I use NSUserdefaults where I save a string. For the checkmark I use this code:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var identifier = defaults.objectForKey("Sort") as! String
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("\(identifier)") as! UITableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    return cell

}
```

But it doesn't work. I always get the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this line:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier) as! UITableViewCell
```

I did not forget to set the cell identifier in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using static cells, in which case you only have 3, you could set up `IBOutlet` in storyboard.

```
@IBOutlet weak var cell1: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var cell2: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var cell3: UITableViewCell!
```

Subsequently, while you are still in storyboard, please set up tags for each cell, by clicking on the `Attributes Inspector` on the right.

For test, I set up the tags from 0 - 2 (i.e., 0, 1, 2).

I am guessing that you are saving a `String` value in you main controller, and once clicked, you would like so that the corresponding cell would have a checkmark by getting that value out of `NSDefault` again.

You could do this in method (Swift-wise: function):

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
```

Here is what I came up as a quick test:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("0", forKey: "Sort")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


    let defaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var aString = defaults.valueForKey("Sort") as? String

    let cellIndex = aString?.toInt()

    if cell1.tag == cellIndex
    {
        cell1.textLabel!.text = "Hallo, I am cell 1"
        cell1.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else if cell2.tag == cellIndex
    {
        cell2.textLabel!.text = "Hello, I am cell 2"
        cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
    else if cell3.tag == cellIndex
    {
        cell3.textLabel!.text = "Hello, I am cell 3"
        cell3.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }

}
```

As test, I set it as `0` and get it back immediately from `NSDefault`; and the first cell is checked with a checkmark.

Answer (score 1):

If you use static table view cells, `tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will **always** return `nil`. This causes the error.

As an alternative, you can set the checkmars in the `viewWillAppear` function. There, you can access the cells via the [`tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/cellForRowAtIndexPath:) function:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as UITableViewCell
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark

    ...
}
```

(replace the values of the `forRow` and `inSection` parameters as you need)

Comment: thank you for your answer. i dont work with this function until yet. can you show me how my code look like to work for my situation?

Comment: Not entirely, because I don't know the specific details. I hope you can use the example in my updated answer.

Comment: thx! the compiler show me an error for your code: Downcast from 'UITableViewCell?' to 'UITableViewCell' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?  So i set a "!" behind UITableViewCell and my app crashed with the error of my first post again

Comment: Sorry - that should've been `as` instead of `as!`. I'm not sure why the `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath` still returns nil. Is index path 0-0 correct ?

Comment: if i remove the "!" behind von as, the compile show the same error. ye, 0-0 havt to be correct - i only have one section with 3 cells

Comment: Good answer. Updated for Swift 4.0:
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let index = IndexPath(row: yourRow, section: yourSection)
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: index)
        cell?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
    }